# Build error with ios-charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks, ios-charts

I have followed the guide [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/charts) to install the ios-charts framework as an embedded binary and step 3 of the guide instructs me to build the project. The build then fails instantly as a result of adding the embedded binary. I have downloaded the most recent version of the framework, and it supposed to compatible with swift 3.

I am using X-code 8 beta, and hence swift 3. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Can't do anything without the exact error output from the compiler.

Comment: why not use cocoapods?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [zip file with project](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/tree/Swift-3.0)
2. Build it
3. In Xcode find product folder, find there Charts product, show in Finder
4. Open your project in xCode
5. Drag & drop bundle(from step 3) to your project in xCode
6. Configure your project settings: in Embedded Binaries use "+" to add charts

Answer (score 0):

1) Use CocoaPods (doc: https://cocoapods.org)

2) Add Charts to your pod file (doc: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

> Add pod 'Charts' to your Podfile. "Charts" is the name of the library.
>
> For Realm support you can specify the subspec in your Podfile as follows:
>
> pod 'Charts/Realm'
>
> Note: pod 'ios-charts' is not the correct library, and refers to a > different project by someone else.

Answer (score -1):

For Swift 3, you should go with CocoaPods.

Write `pod 'Charts/Realm'` this will install exact pod version for chart, then clean and build.